# Is it possible to connect 8 usb cameras to Ubuntu , I'm using a TP-Link 7 ports hub , and I cant find the way to access the cameras at the same time

Tags: usb-drive, webcam, camera, opencv, ros

I'm working on a project on ROS and I need to connect 8 usb cameras , so I bought a usb hub from TP-link but still cant access all the cameras at the same time , could you help me with this ?

Comment: How have you tried to access the cameras? What kind of errors are you seeing? Trying to use that many cameras on a single USB host could possibly exceed the max bandwidth (depending on camera resolution, fps, etc)

Comment: I tried to access 2 cameras only and it didn't work , i tried many ways as opencv , an online website for testing webcams and obs studio , I don't know what is the specific problem but I think it's because the 7 cameras have the same port num

Comment: Could you show the output of `ls /dev | grep video` and/or `lsusb` when you have all cameras connected? What USB camera are you using in particular (are they UVC compatible?)?

Comment: there are a number of possible solutions I have been considering (but not yet taken action on): https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/679748/running-ip-cameras-with-ubuntu-1804-best-solution/ https://www.gaggl.com/2014/02/getting-foscam-ip-cameras-to-work-from-linux-ubuntu/ and finally using a NAS like Synology https://www.synology.com/en-us/surveillance

Comment: I'll try that , thank you

Comment: And yes i can see my cameras when i use lsusb , how can I check if my USB camera UVC compatible? (Fantech c30)

Comment: What's the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way would be to write a javascript/python app that will call your devices output to a web app, otherwise I don't recall there is a multiple webcam viewer on the repository.

You might want to get all the information from your webcams using **v4l2-ctl** (on the v4l-utils package).

A good start would be:

```
v4l2-ctl --all
```